# Can the default message in the `Testing` tab be changed if no tests were found?

Tags: vscode-extensions

Sometimes for many internal reasons, tests are not identified/populated in our vscode extension for testing using vscode [testing api](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/testing). We need to give the user a hint why this is happening and so we need to modify the default message ("no tests have been found in this workspace yet") in the test explorer.
How can I do this?
[image]

Tried giving a default message through testItem, but then the play button is present for it